# Extended express request object not recognized

Tags: typescript

I created a global express request error handler in TypeScript (3.8.3)

```js
import express from 'express'
import { ProblemDocument } from 'http-problem-details'

const registerExpressProblemJsonResponse = (): void => {
  express.response.httpProblemJSON = function(problemDocument): void { // line 5
    this.set('Content-Type', 'application/problem+json')
    this.status(problemDocument.status)
    this.send(problemDocument)
  }
}

export { registerExpressProblemJsonResponse }

import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'

const GlobalRequestErrorHandler = (logger: any) => {
  return (
    err: Error,
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): void => {
    logger.error(`${req.method} ${req.url} Error: ${err}`, { error: err })
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      return res.httpProblemJSON( // line 25
        new ProblemDocument({ status: 500, type: 'https://tempuri.org/error' })
      )
    } else {
      logger.warn(
        `[global-request-error-handler] ${req.method} ${req.url} has an error path returning a response already`
      )
    }
  }
}

export { GlobalRequestErrorHandler }
```

I've extended the express request object (`src/types/types.d.ts`):

```js
import { ProblemDocument } from 'http-problem-details'

declare namespace Express {
  export interface Response {
    httpProblemJSON(problemDocument: ProblemDocument): void
  }
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

I've installed `"@types/express": "^4.17.3"` and `"express": "^4.17.1"`.

When running `tsc`, I get these errors:

```sh
src/index.ts:5:20 - error TS2339: Property 'httpProblemJSON' does not exist on type 'Response<any>'.

5   express.response.httpProblemJSON = function(
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:25:18 - error TS2339: Property 'httpProblemJSON' does not exist on type 'Response<any>'.

25       return res.httpProblemJSON(
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/AlexZeitler/typescript-extend-http-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration for Express is wrong.

It supposes to look like this:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Response {
      httpProblemJSON(problemDocument: ProblemDocument): void
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a repo. It is really strange as it is working in my project.

Comment: I've updated my question and added a link at the end.

Comment: Got it! My mistake and we both did not catch it. 
It was typing Request and you're using Response :) 
`tsc` working fine with this change in your repo :)

Comment: The error now is gone, indeed. There are two interesting things I noticed: In the test file VS Code still shows the error and if I'm using mocha + ts-node using instead of jest, the test now fails with the compiler error. Commit to use mocha: https://github.com/AlexZeitler/typescript-extend-http-request/pull/3/commits/c0e0999934fc793ee7bc11ce481db76accf94c18

Comment: strange. Webstorm also shows an error, but test with Jest runs without any issues!

Comment: This at least fixes the VS Code error: https://github.com/AlexZeitler/typescript-extend-http-request/pull/3/commits/6aa06db0773fdf5e6dc6c5e8713b8c76bb19e7a7
I guess I need to override the tsconfig for `ts-node` somehow...

Comment: You should not need to override config for ts-node I think. It should use base tsconfig in my opinion. 
Anyway, I would appreciate accepting the answer as I still think I helped ;)

Comment: Using `ts-mocha` fixed it: https://github.com/AlexZeitler/typescript-extend-http-request/pull/3/commits/66b6d40879793119836fdfa9d418ce80b50d9d66

Comment: I'd try to fix it to keep it working with Jest to be honest...

Comment: Jest already works as it was already using `ts-jest`. But I get your point: understanding is the key...